# Use an input data variable as a key getting Zapier results (custom integration)

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm having an issue with building a private Zapier integration since Zapier can only use arrays as outputs instead of objects. The array I needs to call is nested 2 levels into my API results, and the key it needs to call is a variable unique to the task called (but I can I can make it part of the input data).

So to get the correct array, the javascript would need to be something like `"return results.custom_field_values[bundle.inputData.id]"`, but I can't find a way to get the input data variable to be accepted in the results like.

Is this possible? I couldn't find a solution in the support documentation.

Here is the call I'm making:

```
const options = {
  url: `https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/custom_field_values.json?subject_type=story&with_subject_id=${bundle.inputData.subject_id}& custom_field_name=Active Assignee`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    'subject_id': bundle.inputData.with_subject_id,
    'display_value': 'Active Assignee'
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results.custom_field_values[bundle.inputData.id];
  });
```

Here is my result when I call just results.custom_field_values:

```
{
  "233451615": {
    "can_edit": true,
    "subject_type": "story",
    "account_id": 4150797,
    "subject_id": 385046515,
    "updated_at": "2019-03-18T13:54:28-07:00",
    "value": [
      638945
    ],
    "display_value": "Irma Davila",
    "setter_id": "10976265",
    "custom_field_id": "181017",
    "created_at": "2019-03-05T07:00:15-08:00",
    "custom_field_name": "Active Assignee",
    "type": "single",
    "id": "233451615"
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is call only the array within the object that in this case is "233451615" (It's the same as the ID). However, even though the object is different every time, it can be provided as a variable via the input.

Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bracket notation instead of dot notation?

something like this :

`results.custom_field_values[{bundle.inputData.id}]`

Also make sure that `bundle.inputData.id` is the correct value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried the syntax you mentioned, but I'm now getting the error: null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(e)'). Any idea what might be up with that?

Comment: I also updated my initial request to have more information of my request and response, so it's easier to understand what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: what is the value of `bundle.inputData.id` ? to me that sounds like a number and you are treating it like its the key of some object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[]` notation [**Ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

Change this

```
"return results.custom_field_values.{bundle.inputData.id}"
```

to this

```
"return results.custom_field_values[bundle.inputData.id]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, after adopting the [], I'm now getting the error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(e)')`. Any idea what might be up with that?

Comment: I also updated my initial request to have more information of my request and response, so it's easier to understand what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Update 2: It turned out my example subject_id and id were wrong, and your suggestion worked perfectly. Unfortunately, now I'm now getting an error that says `Results must be an array, got: undefined, ()`. Do you know if the `"value": [638945],` might be causing issues with it being read as an array?